# Should I use wait for popen

Tags: python, concurrency, process, signals, fork

I'm using `subprocess.Popen` in `playStation` function to run another process which is media player to play radio station. However, when I kill the parent process, it doesn't stop, not killed. Just stuck after pressing `CTRL-C`, `CTRL-Z` or sending `SIGKILL`. Normally, It should be killed immediately. But not.

I feel I exactly do a or some mistake(s). One of them maybe I don't think to wait the media player which is run by `subprocess.Popen` since it plays the radio station until I kill the child. Should I wait? If so, how, where?

If I wait before `return p`, it is stuck.

I try to simplify my code,

```
def playStation(stationAddress):
    # if there is a media player being run, kill it for new one
    killMPlayer = "killall mplayer"
    os.system(killMPlayer)

    radioName = 'mplayer ' + '-playlist ' + stationAddress
    p = subprocess.Popen(radioName.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

    ## the return value is not used I have added it ,maybe necessary
    return p


arr = [ 
        'radio ip address:port 1',
        'radio ip address:port 2',
        'radio ip address:port 3',
        'radio ip address:port 4',
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
        there are more but just simplicity 4 is enough
]

counter = 0

try:
    while True:
        signal.signal(signal.SIGCHLD, signal.SIG_IGN)

        pid = os.fork()


        if pid == 0:

            playStation(arr[counter])

            ### normally playStation does work, control is takeovered by '''mplayer''' !!!!
            exit(0)
        else:
            ### wait until rotary encoder(switcher) is turned
            GPIO.wait_for_edge(CLOCKPIN, GPIO.FALLING)
            sleep(0.5)

            ### stop current child to create new child
            ### stop currently playing radio station to change to new station

            os.kill(pid, signal.SIGTERM)
            #os.waitpid(pid, 0)

            # prevent index out of bound
            if rotary_encoder_turned_left:
                counter = counter - 1
                if counter < 0:
                    counter = 4
            elif rotary_encoder_turned_right:
                counter = counter + 1
                if counter > 4:
                    counter = 0
```

Comment: Shouldn't your `signal.signal` line contain the signal to receive and the method to execute if received? I.e. `signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, method_to_kill_child_process)` See here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html#module-signal

Comment: @TD-Asker no, it's a way not to use wait. I mean it's alternative to wait without carrying out return value.